# License - Can I use Office 365 Home Premium on a business computer?

Tags: microsoft-office, license, office365

I'm thinking about buying Office 365 (aka. 2013) for my own PCs (2), and I could give one copy to the PC here that belongs to a company. The PC also got an Office 2007 (legal), but I'm no legal expert.

I looked at the FAQ/site, but it mentions no such thing.
So. **Can I install it on a PC that belongs to a business?**
The machines are located at the same place, it's a family business.

Comment: If I mistyped any product/service names, please edit my Q.

Comment: If I'm getting you right you mean you want share one copy on 2 pc's?

Comment: @avirk: You get 5 copies of Word/Excel, etc. I want to install 2 on my own personal computers, and ONE copy on a business PC.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [MS Office](http://office.microsoft.com/en-in/products/microsoft-office-for-home-and-school-faq-FX102926087.aspx#) FAQ you can't use it for business purpose.

[image]

Comment: Could you copy out the relevant part? (or include a picture of it.)

Comment: @Shiki as you said, done!

Comment: @Shiki hope you would not mind to mark it accepted in that case? :)

Comment: 5 years later this information doesn't seem correct any more. The page this answer links to seems to no longer contain any information about restriction of where the applications can be used. Other sources states that the licenses no longer contain any such restrictions.