# Can Office 2016 "Personal" be used for professional / business / commercial uses?

Tags: microsoft-office, license, microsoft-office-2016

Microsoft Office 2007 Home and Student Edition came with a licensing stipulation that the software was not allowed to be used for business, professional or commercial uses. A variant of the software without this restriction was much more expensive (more than double, if I remember correctly). I believe the 2013 edition was the same.

I'm currently choosing between the Personal and Business versions of Office 2016, which are very similarly priced (but the Personal bundle suits my needs better). I can't see any indication of any similar restriction.

So far, however, all I've been able to find is marketing info and press releases. None make any mention of any restriction in usage or any distinction between commercial and non-commercial use - but maybe there is such a restriction and they just simply chose to not mention it. I can't even find the EULA.

Is there any such restriction on Office Personal 2016?

---

For the opposite of this question, see [Can I use Office 365 Business Premium at home for personal use?](https://superuser.com/questions/834998/can-i-use-office-365-business-premium-at-home-for-personal-use)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They hid this information in most of their marketing pages, even up to the buying page, but [the full product listing on their "store" page](http://www.microsoftstore.com/store/msusa/en_US/pdp/Office-365-Personal/productID.297833200) does specify non-commercial use:

> ### Additional System Requirements
>
> Non-commercial use.
>
> Internet functionality requires an Internet connection.
>
> ...

So the same restriction is still there, they're just much quieter about it now.